# Angular 2 How to redirect to 404 or other path if the path does not exist

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I was trying to redirect 404 `/` other path if the path does not exist in angular 2

I tried research there is some method for angular 1 but not angular 2.

Here is my code :

```
@RouteConfig([
{
    path: '/news',
    name: 'HackerList',
    component: HackerListComponent,
    useAsDefault: true
},
{
    path: '/news/page/:page',
    name: 'TopStoriesPage',
    component: HackerListComponent
},
{
    path: '/comments/:id',
    name: 'CommentPage',
    component: HackerCommentComponent
}
])
```

So example if I redirect to `/news/page/` then it works and it return me an empty page how do you handle this kind of case happen?

Comment: What are you using for routing?

Comment: I use @RouteConfig to create route

Answer (score 276, accepted):

**For version v2.2.2 and newer**

In version v2.2.2 and up, **name** property no longer exists and it shouldn't be used to define the route. *path* should be used instead of *name* and *no leading slash* is needed on the path. In this case use `path: '404'` instead of `path: '/404'`:

```
 {path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent},
 {path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}
```

**For versions older than v2.2.2**

you can use `{path: '/*path', redirectTo: ['redirectPathName']}`:

```
{path: '/home/...', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent}
{path: '/', redirectTo: ['Home']},
{path: '/user/...', name: 'User', component: UserComponent},
{path: '/404', name: 'NotFound', component: NotFoundComponent},

{path: '/*path', redirectTo: ['NotFound']}
```

if no path matches then redirect to `NotFound` path

Comment: I build a angular test project and there I used this technique. `/*` means anything. get idea from **Angular Cheat Sheet**  *Routing and Navigation* part . https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cheatsheet.html

Comment: but this will still return status 200. How do I return 404?

Comment: It seems that this does not work anymore in combination with nested routing. When you check the [official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) you can see that they use the technique at the beginning but later they remove it (without mentioning it again)

Comment: What if, Each module contains own routes. & one of module route contains `{path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}` then next all modules url patterns never called it always redirect to `/404`.
Does it check all modules routes before matching `**` ?

Comment: @ShaishabRoy Why `{path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent}, {path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}` IMO this is enough: `{ path: "**", component: NotFoundComponent }`

Comment: @DiPix yes you can do that also :)

Comment: It still works with nested routes. Just had to put the 404 and path routes after all my other routes. Ordering matters after all

Comment: for me this solution dont work when use children paths

Comment: @ShaishabRoy Thanks for the answer,but if I use path as ** ,I was not able to hit url with Query Params.If I hit any url passing query params it is redirecting to 404 page.Can you please help on this.

Answer (score 32):

My preferred option on **2.0.0** and up is to create a 404 route and also allow a ** route path to resolve to the same component. This allows you to log and display more information about the invalid route rather than a plain redirect which can act to hide the error.

Simple 404 example:

```
{ path '/', component: HomeComponent },
// All your other routes should come first    
{ path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent },
{ path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
```

To display the incorrect route information add in import to router within NotFoundComponent:

`import { Router } from '@angular/router';`

Add it to the constructior of NotFoundComponent:

`constructor(public router: Router) { }`

Then you're ready to reference it from your HTML template e.g.

`The page <span style="font-style: italic">{{router.url}}</span> was not found.`

Comment: When I try your solution, all the routes are redirecting to 404. What looks like your others routes?

Comment: It doesn't redirect, it loads the NotFoundComponent, the original/invalid path will still be in the URL on the page.

Comment: Although this approach appears the same, the main benefit of this approach is that you retain the routing information. A simple redirect as per the other answers lose context and thus you can't then display what went wrong or provide logging beyond a generic "404" page.

Comment: @Ben you need to provide the rest of your routing information before the 404 routes, as the 404 routes act as a fall through. In the case as per the sample routes only the "/" path will work.

Comment: This is the right way to do it! Why would someone want to redirect in case of a 404? In case of a 404, we just need to display a 404 component and stay on that invalid url. Plus, in case of a redirect... if I try to navigate to `/invalid-path` and then get redirected to `/404`, then if I click the browser "back" button, wouldn't that get me to `/invalid-path` and back to `/404` again?

Answer (score 29):

As Angular moved on with the release, I faced this same issue. As per version **2.1.0** the `Route` interface looks like:

```
export interface Route {
    path?: string;
    pathMatch?: string;
    component?: Type<any>;
    redirectTo?: string;
    outlet?: string;
    canActivate?: any[];
    canActivateChild?: any[];
    canDeactivate?: any[];
    canLoad?: any[];
    data?: Data;
    resolve?: ResolveData;
    children?: Route[];
    loadChildren?: LoadChildren;
}
```

So my solutions was the following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '404' }
];
```

Comment: This works in Angular 5 (similar to your solution):

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '404', component: NotfoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' }
];

Comment: `**` should be the last route in the list,..

Comment: @Lonely your comment should be answer of its own! It saved me hours of my work and my sanity!!

Answer (score 11):

As shaishab roy says, in the cheat sheet you can find the answer.

But in his answer, the given response was :

> ```
> {path: '/home/...', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent}
> {path: '/', redirectTo: ['Home']},
> {path: '/user/...', name: 'User', component: UserComponent},
> {path: '/404', name: 'NotFound', component: NotFoundComponent},
>
> {path: '/*path', redirectTo: ['NotFound']}
> ```

For some reasons, it doesn't works on my side, so I tried instead :

```
{path: '/**', redirectTo: ['NotFound']}
```

and it works. Be careful and don't forget that you need to put it at the end, or else you will often have the 404 error page ;).

Comment: I think the reason of your side isn't working is because we are still in beta that time and they did change some on the release ver.
btw thx for updating the answer =D

Answer (score 6):

make sure ,use this 404 route wrote on the bottom of the code.

syntax will be like

```
{
    path: 'page-not-found', 
    component: PagenotfoundComponent
},
{
    path: '**', 
    redirectTo: '/page-not-found'
},
```

Thank you