# Angular: 404 page but keep url

Tags: javascript, angular

I wrote a custom 404 page in Angular 4 and want to keep the wrong url that was entered.
You can see the behavior on github for example. They display a 404 page for not existing urls. Example: https://github.com/cdkdfjkdjf

Currently I configured my router like this:

```
{ path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '404' }
```

Any idea how to archive this?

Comment: Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260839/angular-2-how-to-redirect-to-404-or-other-path-if-the-path-does-not-exist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 How to redirect to 404 or other path if the path does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260839/angular-2-how-to-redirect-to-404-or-other-path-if-the-path-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 11):

The solution is very simple:

```
 { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
```